# Session Path not working

Tags: php, session, nginx

I have setup a nginx webserver, I made a login script that worked however I was changing permissions on that directory and session no longer works.

The owner and group is www-data of all files/directories, The permissions of both files/directories for everything is 750

(I know how unsafe that is, but it's temp until I get everything to work)

In php.ini (/etc/php5/fpm/) I set `session.save_path "/tmp/php5"`

I have checked both `/var/lib/php5` and my path `/tmp/php5`

but no session files are being created. However If I set `session_save_path('/tmp/php5');` in my php file the sessions seem to work.

Any idea what is going on here??

Comment: What do you get if you output `ini_get('session.save_path')` before trying to set the variable?

Comment: It says /tmp/php5 now. What permissions should that folder be set at?

Comment: What's the OS, as I would have expected configuration in `/etc/php-fpm.ini` or `/etc/php-fpm.d`?

Comment: @Cez I'm using debian 7, nginx, and php5-fpm. It's located in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, I changed the directory correctly now It won't create so I think it's a permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

I got it working correctly by changing the directory and setting the permissions to 1777.